# How can I link an input to an object's attribute and update that attribute as you click on it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-templates

Given these model, view, and template files:

`models.py`

```
class Item(models.Model):
    class Included(models.IntegerChoices):
        YES = 1
        NO = 0

    included = models.IntegerField(choices=Included.choices, default=Included.YES)
    name = models.CharField()
```

`views.py`

```
def index(request):
    items = Item.objects.all()

    context = {
                'items':item
                }

    return render(request, template.html, context(
```

`template.html`

```
{% for item in items %}
    {{ item.name }}
    <input type="checkbox">
{% endfor %}
```

How can I do it such that the checkbox reflects if the `Item` it's with is included or not?

How can I change if it's included or not by just ticking the checkbox?

In general, how can I link an input to an object's attribute and update that attribute as you click on it?

I don't think it would be feasible to use `forms` here, as it only changes a field. Plus if it's possible, do it realtime. Forms won't update a page unless you refresh it afaik, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an `onChange` handler to the checkbox, and submit a `POST` request when the checkbox is clicked.

```js
document.querySelector('#cbox').addEventListener('change', function (e) {
  var item_id = this.getAttribute('data-item-id')
  var checked = this.checked
  
  console.log('Item ID:', item_id)
  console.log('Checkbox is checked?', checked)
  
  //fetch('url here', {
  //  method: 'POST',
  //  body: {item_id: item_id, checked: checked}
  //});
})
```

```html
<input id="cbox" data-item-id="{{ item.id }}" type="checkbox" />
```

And then your view would look something like this:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
def handleCheckbox(request):
    if request.POST:
        item_id = request.POST['item_id']
        checked = 1 if request.POST['checked'] == True else 0
        
        item = Item.objects.get(id=item_id)
        item.included = checked
        item.save()

        return JsonResponse({'message': 'Success'})
```